# Selenium WebDriver Factory picking same driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am making an WinForms application, using Visual Studio with Selenium webdriver. I am running some tests using different browser for each test, that are launch at the click of different winforms buttons.

I have created an Webdriver Factory class as follows:

```
class BrowserFactory
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<string, IWebDriver> Drivers = new Dictionary<string, IWebDriver>();
        private static IWebDriver driver;

        public static IWebDriver Driver
        {
            get
            {
                if (driver == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method InitBrowser.");
                return driver;
            }
            private set
            {
                driver = value;
            }
        }

        public static void InitBrowser(string browserName)
        {
            switch (browserName)
            {
                case "Firefox":
                    if (driver == null)
                    {
                        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
                        options.Profile = profile;
                        options.BrowserExecutableLocation = $@"{EcrisAdreseFrameW.Properties.Settings.Default["caleAppData"]}\Internet JS4\App\firefox64\firefox.exe";
                        FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService($@"{EcrisAdreseFrameW.Properties.Settings.Default["caleAppData"]}");
                        driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
                        Drivers.Add("Firefox", driver);
                    }
                    break;

                case "Chrome":
                    if (driver == null)
                    {
                        var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService($@"{EcrisAdreseFrameW.Properties.Settings.Default["caleAppData"]}\ChromeDriver");
                        var options = new ChromeOptions();
                        service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
                        options.BinaryLocation = $@"{EcrisAdreseFrameW.Properties.Settings.Default["caleAppData"]}\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe";

                        options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
                      driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);

                      Drivers.Add("ChromeAscuns", driver);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The code for first button:

```
BrowserFactory.InitBrowser("Firefox");
BrowserFactory.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

The code for the second button:

```
BrowserFactory.InitBrowser("Chrome");
BrowserFactory.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bing.com");
```

When I click any of the buttons, it launches the correct webdriver (Firefox for first button and Chrome for the second). However, when I click the other button, it uses the same webdriver browser as the first occurence.

What am I missing in the code?

Comment: U told it what to do if (driver == null), but what about when if (driver != null)?

Comment: @Somber, you mean in the `public static IWebDriver Driver`? If it is not null, it skips the throwexception line. I have tried putting this line in brackets, but it doesn't make a difference. I actually got the code from https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/browser-factory-or-webdriver-factory/.

Comment: I mean this  case "Firefox": if (driver == null) so if u try to switch drivers during test run and driver is not null it skips creation of new driver and uses old one, no?

Comment: @Somber, yes. that is the logic. I have assumed it uses the value of the driver that it was already set. I don't fully understand the code and I cannot find further references.

Comment: Did you mean use use `BrowserFactory.driver` (lower case 'd') and `BrowserFactory.Driver` (upper case 'D') or is that just a typo in your question?

Comment: So if u want to switch driver, you must replace active driver with new one, so you must not check, whether it is null or not, when you create new driver

Comment: @GregBurghardt, actually, `BrowserFactory.Driver` was suggested in the aboved mentioned article. I don't understand the reason for the `public static IWebDriver Driver` with get set statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want to cache web drivers and reuse them. The problem is you are checking to see if a "driver" is already created, and if not create one, and cache that instance in a dictionary.

You need to consult the dictionary first before entering the `switch` statement and exit the method prematurely if a web driver by that name already exists. You also need to assume that when you fall in to the `switch` statement you will *always* be creating a new web driver.

```cs
public static void InitBrowser(string browserName)
{
    if (Drivers.ContainsKey(browserName))
    {
        // Switch to existing web driver
        driver = Drivers[browserName];

        return;
    }

    // Initialize new web driver
    switch (browserName)
    {
        case "Firefox":
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.Profile = profile;
            options.BrowserExecutableLocation = $@"{EcrisAdreseFrameW.Properties.Settings.Default["caleAppData"]}\Internet JS4\App\firefox64\firefox.exe";
            FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService($@"{EcrisAdreseFrameW.Properties.Settings.Default["caleAppData"]}");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
            Drivers.Add("Firefox", driver);
            break;

        case "Chrome":
            var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService($@"{EcrisAdreseFrameW.Properties.Settings.Default["caleAppData"]}\ChromeDriver");
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            options.BinaryLocation = $@"{EcrisAdreseFrameW.Properties.Settings.Default["caleAppData"]}\GoogleChromePortable\App\Chrome-bin\chrome.exe";
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
            Drivers.Add("ChromeAscuns", driver);
            break;
    }
}
```